# How Do I Edit a Google Sheet after Creating It Using Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I possess many years of programming experience in Visual Basic for Applications, but now I'm attempting to learn automation in the Google Drive environment. Feels like I'm starting from scratch. Much appreciation from anyone who can help.

The script below does not work because it first runs saveAsSpreadsheet on the source sheet (active sheet), and then also runs copyValuesToRange on the source sheet (active sheet). I want to run copyValuesToRange on the NEW sheet which was produced by the first command saveAsSpreadsheet.

**How do I reference the newly generated sheet?** (in my example, it's called NewDocName, which is a value pulled from a named range in the source sheet)

Thanks!!

-CP

```
function BackupPayroll(){
    saveAsSpreadsheet();
    copyValuesToRange();
}

function saveAsSpreadsheet(){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var NewDocName = sheet.getRangeByName('Backup').getValues(); 
    var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
    DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(NewDocName, destFolder); 
}

function copyValuesToRange(sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd) {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
    var source = ss.getSheets()[3];
    var destination = ss.getSheets()[3];
    var range = source.getRange("A1:P200");

    range.copyValuesToRange(destination, 1, 16, 1, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about following sample?

It returns ID of new spreadsheet at `saveAsSpreadsheet()`, and at `copyValuesToRange()` the new spreadsheet is opened using the ID.

#### Script :

```
function BackupPayroll(){
  var id = saveAsSpreadsheet();
  copyValuesToRange(id, null, null, null, null, null);
}

function saveAsSpreadsheet(){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var NewDocName = sheet.getRangeByName('Backup').getValues(); 
  var destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"); 
  var newsheet = DriveApp.getFileById(sheet.getId()).makeCopy(NewDocName, destFolder); 
  return newsheet.getId();
}

function copyValuesToRange(id, sheet, column, columnEnd, row, rowEnd) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(id);
  var source = ss.getSheets()[3];
  var destination = ss.getSheets()[3];
  var range = source.getRange("A1:P200");

  range.copyValuesToRange(destination, 1, 16, 1, 200);
}
```

If I misunderstand your question, I'm sorry.

Comment: this is it! Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks @Tanaike. Sorry for the delay. I gave the answer an up-vote, and thought that would consider it accepted. Apparently I had to click on the checkmark. Now done.

Comment: @CPriestley No problem. Thank you, too.